# Gibbs sampler from conditional distribution

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I am trying to propose Gibbs sampling with the density below,

$$p(y_1,y_2,y_3)\propto \exp [-({{y}_{1}}+{{y}_{2}}+{{y}_{3}}+{{\theta}_{12}{y_1}{y_2}}+{{\theta }_{13}{y_3}{y_1}}+{{\theta }_{23}{y_2}{y_3}})]$$

where, $({{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}},{{y}_{3}})\in R_{+}^{3}$ and ${{\theta }_{ij}}=i+j$

How do I find the full conditional distribution?

And then, I'll generate sample $\{(y_{1}^{i},y_{2}^{i},y_{3}^{i})\}$ for $i=1,...n$.

I understand Gibbs sampling, sample one variable while keep others fixed.

Comment: Are the double subscripts in the displaymath deliberate? If so, what do they mean?

Comment: I could be mistaken, let me rewrite!

Comment: I have edited your formula as I think you mean the double exponential distribution (used by Julian Besag in several of his papers). I do not understand the $\theta_{ij}=i+j$. Otherwise, the conditionals are determined by fixing all $y_i$'s but one. You then get a standard distribution, as detailed in our [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441919392?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441919392).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There you go-
Gibbs Sampler:
The burning period is to reach some stationarity in the samples

```
burning_period=5000
iterations=1000
y=matrix(nrow=(burning_period+iterations),ncol=3)
a=matrix(nrow=iterations,ncol=3)

y[1,1]=0.5        #Initial Sample 
y[1,2]=0.6
y[1,3]=0.2   

 for(i in 2:(burning_period+iterations)){

     #I have put 3,3,4 as my theta's. You may make the code generic for any choice of theta's.
     t= 1+3*y[i-1,2]+4*y[i-1,3]
     # Use t or t*-1 based on your requirement.
     t=rexp(1,t)  

     y[i,1]=t
     t= 1+3*y[i,1]+5*y[i-1,3]   
     y[i,2]=rexp(1,t)

     t=1+4*y[i,1]+5*y[i,2]
     y[i,3]=rexp(1,t)  
    }
posteriorSample=y[(burning_period+1) : (burning_period+iterations), ]
```

Comment: I am working my way to there, will reply soon once I get there.  thanks!

Comment: I think rexp() really does the trick, without it, generating y1, y2, y3 would take more work, maybe something like inverse transformation?  just a random comment.

Comment: Yes- the theta's were for your manual tweaking :)

Answer (score 3):

The full conditional distributions can be found by fixing the values of the two "other" variables, then combining all the terms that you can combine and seeing what you get:

$p(y_1|y_2,y_3) \propto \exp\{-(1+\theta_{12}y_2+\theta_{13}y_3)y_1\}$

which is evidently an exponential distribution with parameter $1+\theta_{12}y_2+\theta_{13}y_3$, and similarly for $p(y_2|y_1,y_3)$, which is an exponential distribution with parameter $1 + \theta_{12}y_1 + \theta_{23}y_3$, and $p(y_3|y_1,y_2)$, which is an exponential distribution with parameter $1 + \theta_{13}y_1 + \theta_{23}y_2$.

Your Gibbs sampler will start with some values for $y_1, y_2, y_3$ and just loop over the three conditional distributions, again and again, generating exponential variates from the appropriate distribution and substituting in the current values for the the appropriate $y_i$ as it goes.  Naturally you'll have to discard some initial block of variates to get rid of burn-in effects.

Comment: Yes, you should, given that you know what they are.

Comment: I think I can answer that myself with a yes, as pointed out Praneeth's answer.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Our comments crossed, I see!  Yes, Praneeth's code looks good to me, except of course your thetas are 3, 4, and 5 instead of 3, 3, and 4.

Comment: Why is it ok to ignore the last term inside the exponential?(see below)  I know it is a constant, but it will affect the probability in the end when you raise e to the power of that constant. $p({{y}_{1}}|{{y}_{2}},{{y}_{3}})\propto \exp \{-(1+{{\theta }_{12}}{{y}_{2}}+{{\theta }_{13}}{{y}_{3}}){{y}_{1}}+({{y}_{2}}+{{y}_{3}}+{{\theta }_{23}}{{y}_{2}}{{y}_{3}})\}$

Comment: We can ignore the last term inside the exponential because it disappears when you apply the constant of integration to get the exact distribution.  (Also, because when using the proportionality symbol, it's ok to neglect multiplicative constants.)

Comment: I see, you are right, what was I thinking?  Basically, in the end, the normalizing constant will replace whatever I got in that constant term.

Comment: But, what's the idea behind "you can sample without the normalizing constant and get the same sample."  Clearly, they are two different densities, but still produce the same sample X1, X2,...,Xn?

Comment: By typing up my own question really helps me think.  So, I guess, the how the samples X1,...,Xn behave is already fixed(normal, gamma...), the normalizing constant is only there to help the density integrate to 1.

Comment: Exactly so.  Rejection sampling based on the maximum possible value of an unnormalized pdf with a finite upper bound will give you a sample from the "correct" dist'n, although it may be very inefficient relative to a sampling scheme based on the normalized pdf (or cdf.)  (I, too, have discovered that writing out a question or problem forces me to clarify it, and that often makes the answer much clearer.)

Comment: Could you please tell me how you obtain the conditional probability $p(y_1|y_2, y_3)$?